# Vinagre VNC freezes permanently

Tags: vnc, debian

I have changed laptop, and although I use exactly the same setup as before, VNC via Vinagre is freezing all the time, literally every ten or twenty seconds when anything happens on the screen. I can press disconnect/connect and it's back without problem. The Pi is a Pi 4B with Raspbian Buster, with VNC Connect (RealVNC) "Raspberry Pi  Edition". The laptop is using Debian 11, Vinagre as client. My old system on the desktop was Debian 10, no issues. I suspect it's the Wayland change or something like that. Should I switch to a different VNC client? It's ultra annoying. I don't want to switch back to X11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bug of Vinagre - wouldn't be the only Gnome app in Debian 11 that has issues. Installing TigerVNC (`tigervnc-viewer`) solves this, it works without interruption.